# Ruby Regex Replace Characters Between Two Numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

Im trying to write a string cleaner that removes underscores, but replaces them with dots when between numbers (ie, when there is a version number in the string).

```
 1_1_OS_And_Network_Specific_Config
```

I would like this string to come out like

```
 1.1 OS And Network Specific Config
```

I can replace the underscores easy enough, but im having trouble matching the character between the numbers to replace with the dot.

```
\d_\d
```

Seems to match the two digits with the underscore .. but if there is three, like 3.4.1 it doesnt.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `\d(_\d)*` maybe? not tested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, replace the underscores between digits:

```
subject = subject.gsub(/(?<=\d)_(?=\d)/, '.')
```

`(?<=\d)` and `(?=\d)` are [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

They make sure that there is a digit before (`(?<=\d)`)  and after (`(?=\d)`) the current location, but they don't actually become part of the match.

Then, remove the rest of the underscores:

```
subject = subject.gsub(/_/, ' ')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thats exactly what im after, and a great explanation too. Thank you very much!

Comment: This could be simplified/shortened using `subject = subject.gsub(/(?<=\d)_(?=\d)/, '.').gsub(/_/, ' ')`

Comment: One thing .. Im trying to use this in Javascript, but im getting "Invalid group" .. eg  regex = new RegExp("(?<=\d)_(?=\d)");